# Notice: Undefined index

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade, vendor

I'm trying to update my Components with `magento-cli` `setup:upgrade` and I'm getting an error:

> Notice: Undefined index: websites in
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php
>   on line 261

I've tried `setup:di:compile` but the error is still there.

Does anyone know what causes the error?

Comment: Check you env.php file, it might be overwritten. Try to get a sample one and configure it to match your server.

Comment: Which Magento version you are using?

Comment: It might be in config or system xml, check your `system xml` or `config.xml` file (of your custom module)